# How to show that $E(1_{T_y<\infty}M_{T_y})=yE(1_{T_y<\infty})$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

> Let $M$ be a martingale with continuous sample paths with $M_0=x\ge 0$. We assume that $M_t\ge 0$ for every $t\ge 0$ and $M_t\to 0$ as $t\to \infty$ a.s. Show that for every $y>x$,
> $$
> P(\sup_{t\ge 0}M_t\ge y)=\frac{x}{y}.
> $$

My solution is as follows. Let $T_y:=\inf\{t: M_t=y\}$. Denote by $X_t:=M_{t\land T_y}$ the stopped process (this is a martingale). Since $|X_t|\le y$ is bounded, $X_t$ is uniformly integrable. From optional stopping time theorem,
$$
x=EM_0=EX_0=EX_{T_y}=E M_{T_y}
$$

Since it is enough to show that $$
yP(T_y\le t)=x
$$
where $P(\sup_{t\ge 0}M_t\ge y)=P(T_y\le t)$.

**[Comment: this seems not correct? Is it $P(\sup_{t\ge 0}M_t\ge y)=P(T_y\le \infty)$?]**

I do not know how to go to the next step. I guess
$$
E M_{T_y}=yP(T_y\le \infty) ?  \, (*)
$$

Since for any stopping time
$$
M_{T_y}=1_{T_y<\infty}M_{T_y}+1_{T_y=\infty}M_{\infty}=1_{T_y<\infty}M_{T_y}
$$
where the second part is zero.

The LHS in (*) becomes
$$
E M_{T_y}=E(1_{T_y<\infty}M_{T_y})?=yE(1_{T_y<\infty})
$$

Comment: $\sup_{t \geq 0} M_t$?

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Yes! Thanks. I edited it.

Comment: Then I assume that [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239524/prove-mathbbp-sup-t-geq-0-m-t-x-mid-mathcalf-0-1-wedge-fracm?rq=1) is useful , or even [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3490501/prove-that-mathbbpt-y-infty-fracay?rq=1).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer No, my question is one step in the proof. Their proof is the same as my idea. I am stuck one step in the proof.

Comment: But then you've also got over the step : once you have seen that $E M_{T_y} = y E(1_{T_y<\infty})$, then this is equal to $x$ so $\frac{x}{y} = E(1_{T_y < \infty}) = P(\sup_{t \geq 0} M_t \geq y)$, which you can check by seeing that the two events inside are the same.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer That is my question. How to get $E(1_{T_y<\infty}M_{T_y})=yE(1_{T_y<\infty})$? Is this because $M_{T_y}=y$?

Comment: It's because $M_{T_y}=y1_{T_y < \infty}$. If $T_y$ is finite, then at $T_y$ the process $M$ must be $y$ because it has continuous sample paths. If $T_y = \infty$ then $M_{T_y} = M_{\infty} =0$, so that's why that equality works.